# SQL database schema from diagram class

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, relational-database, class-diagram

I created a class diagram that I want to transform into a database in sql server 2008. I implemented the CREATE scripts with the relations and foreign keys but when I try to compile it online (https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/) I always have the same error:
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'CREATE TABLE CONTRAT ( CONTRAT_ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Num_CONTRAT VARCHAR(50) N' at line 18**

Can you please help me verify the DB from the diagram?

Diagram : 
[Class Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1MMX.png)

SQL code :

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT
(
Client_ID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
Type_Client VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL CHECK (Type_Client IN('Physique', 'Morale')),
Date_creation_client DATETIME NOT NULL, 
CIN INT NULL,
Nom Varchar(40) NULL,
Prenom Varchar(40) NULL,
Sexe Varchar(20) NULL,
Tel INT NULL,
Date_Naissance DATE NULL,
Etat_civil Varchar(20) NULL,
Nationalite Varchar(40) NULL,
Adresse Varchar (50) NULL,
Ville Varchar (20) NULL,
Titre Varchar (50) NULL,
Nature_juridique Varchar(20) NULL,
ID_SIRET Varchar(40) NULL
);


CREATE TABLE CONTRAT
(
CONTRAT_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Num_CONTRAT VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Type_CONTRAT Varchar(40),
Flotant Varchar(4) NOT NULL CHECK (Flotant IN('Oui', 'Non')),
Resilie Varchar(4) NOT NULL CHECK (Resilie IN('Oui', 'Non')),
Date_souscription DATE NULL, 
Dte_effet DATE NULL,
Fractionnement VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL CHECK (Fractionnement IN('trimestriel', 'semestriel','annuel')),
Fk_COMPAGNY_ID  INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES COMPAGNIES(COMPAGNY_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE QUITANCE 
(
QUITANCE_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Echeance DATE NOT NULL,
Prime_net DECIMAL NULL,
Taxe DECIMAL NULL, 
DATE_Creation DATE NOT NULL,
FK_CONTRAT_ID INT UNIQUE FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CONTRAT(CONTRAT_ID),
FK_Client_ID INT UNIQUE FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Client(Client_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE OBJET_ASSURE
(

OBJET_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Type_objet VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL;
Marque_automobile VARCHAR(25) NULL,
Immatriculation_automobile VARCHAR(25) NULL,
Puissance_automobile VARCHAR(25) NULL,
valeur_automobile VARCHAR(25) NULL,
destination_voyage VARCHAR(25) NULL,
Debut_voyage DATE NULL,
Fin_voyage DATE NULL,
Adresse_incendie VARCHAR(25) NULL,
valeur_incendie VARCHAR(25) NULL,
age_assurance_vie INT NULL,
dossier_medical_exist VARCHAR(4) NULL CHECK (dossier_medical_exist IN('Oui', 'Non')),
Fk_CONTRAT_ID  INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CONTRAT(CONTRAT_ID)
);


CREATE TABLE COMPAGNIES
(
COMPAGNY_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Nom VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL;
Adresse VARCHAR(25)
);


CREATE TABLE Encaissement
(
ID_Encaissement INT PRIMARY KEY,
DATE_JOURNEE DATE NOT NULL,
type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL CHECK (type IN('Espece', 'Cheque')),
type2 VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL CHECK (type2 IN('C', 'T', 'R')),
Montant Decimal NOT NULL,
FK_CONTRAT_ID INT UNIQUE FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CONTRAT(CONTRAT_ID),
FK_QUITANCE_ID INT UNIQUE FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES QUITANCE(QUITANCE_ID),
);



CREATE TABLE Feuille_Encaissement
(
ID_Feuille INT PRIMARY KEY,
DATE_JOURNEE DATE NOT NULL,
statut VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL CHECK (type IN('ouverte', 'fermee')),
Total_CE DECIMAL NOT NULL,
Total_TE DECIMAL NOT NULL,
Total_CC DECIMAL NOT NULL,
Total_TC DECIMAL NOT NULL,
Total_ES DECIMAL NOT NULL,
Total_CH DECIMAL NOT NULL,
);
```

**EDIT 1 :**

Thanks to @Larnu I corrected the syntax errors : 
[Updated Script](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=089196d22c890502e31edda4d80c3efc)

And I also updates my diagram to : 
[Updated diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c88eN.png)

As you can see "Feuille_Encaissement" is an aggregation of multiple "Encaissement" (Exactly "Feuille_Encaissement" has 0..4 "Encaissement" using the date field "Date_journee" ). How to implement that in SQL ? and is there another solution to impelement that ? I want to store all "Encaissement" row to "Feuille_Encaissement" where the "date_journee" is equivalent.

**EDIT 2  :** 
So what I want to do is :
* Implement a Cron job to create one "Feuille_Encaissement" Every day with a date column "date_journee" and obtain all "Encaissement" objects where Feuille_Encaissement.date_journée == Encaissement.date_journee

- Do calculations and fill  "Feuille_Encaissement" columns

  In conclusion, I want a page with a date containing "Feuille_Encaissement" columns and the all "Encaissement" data of that DATE.

Comment: Line 53 (`Type_objet varchar(25) NOT NULL;`) should end in a comma (`,`) not a semi-colon (`;`). Same error on line 72 (`Nom varchar(25) NOT NULL;`).

Comment: @Larnu It's the same error, please check it here : https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/

Comment: Also, you should really declare your scale and precision for your `decimal` datatypes. Unless you really do want a `decimal(18,10)`.

Comment: If you correct those 2 semi colons ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f7b50c9a4aeb94b1ae1ceb01cbc723bb)), you get an error on `CHECK (type IN ('ouverte', 'fermee'))`, because there is no column `type` in the table `Feuille_Encaissement`. Reading the error messages is really useful here. Stack overflow isn't a debugging website; take your time to read the errors.

Comment: Also, on a side on, I assume `tel` is telephone number. `int` is a poor choice for storing a telephone "number". Telephone numebrs can start with leading zero's, contain characters like `+` and `()` for country codes and extensions, etc. A `varchar(20)` is a far better candidate.

Comment: Also, perhaps the column check constraint should be `statut VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL CHECK (statut IN('ouverte', 'fermee')),`.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks , please check EDIT 1

Comment: I can't say I really understand what you're saying there, but your statement *"I want to store all "Encaissement" row to "Feuille_Encaissement""*  infers you want a many-to-many relationship. If so, you need to use a further table that can build that relationship; a single column can't hold multiple values. These are often referred to as "Joining" or "bridging" tables.

Comment: I don't think it's many-to-many , because I need 1 "Feuille_Encaissement" object containing 0..* "Encaissement"  objects and show them using the date column "Date_journee", isn't it 1-to-many ?

Comment: @Larnu I just need the "Feuille_Encaissement" to store data and display the per day.

Comment: So I think to create Cron job to create each day a row in "Feuille_Encaissement" with today date , and in every operation in "ENCAIssement" I insert it in  "Feuille_Encaissement"

Comment: If it is meant to be `statut` instead of `type`, then there's no reason to declare `statut` as a `varchar(20)`. Both values (`'ouverte'` and `'fermee'`) are far shorter than 20 characters. Define `statut` as a `varchar(7)`..